# What are the best resources for Vastu Shastra?

Tags: scripture, vastu-shastra

Can any one please describe the resources for *Vashtu Shashtra* ?

Comment: Saiva agamas are one of the parts of vasthu sashtra. They talk about how temples to be built..

Answer (score 8):

Sthapatya Veda is an upaveda of Atharvaveda.

Vishwakarma is believed to be an expounder of Vashtu Shashtra also known as (or includes) Shilp Shashtra.

Following are the list of Sanskrit literature (treatise) on Vastu Shashatra from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vastu_shastra#Vastu_Shastras_.E2.80.94_Sanskrit_treatises_on_architecture):

> - Manasara
> - Brhat samhita
> - Mayamata
> - Anka sastra
> - Aparajita Vastu Sastra
> - Maha-agamas (28 books, each with 12 to 75 chapters)
> - Ayadi Lakshana
> - Aramadi Pratishtha Paddhati (includes garden design)
> - Kasyapiya
> - Kupadi Jala Sthana Lakshana
> - Kshetra Nirmana Vidhi (preparation of land and foundation of buildings including temples)
> - Gargya samhita (pillars, doors, windows, wall design and architecture)
> - Griha Pithika (types of houses and their construction)
> - Ghattotsarga Suchanika (riverfront and steps architecture)
> - Chakra sastra
> - Jnana ratna kosha
> - Vastu sarani (measurement, ratio and design layouts of objects, particularly buildings)
> - Devalaya Lakshana (treatise on construction of temples)
> - Dhruvadi shodasa gehani (guidelines for arrangement of buildings with respect to each other for harmony)
> - Nava sastra (36 books, most lost)
> - Agni Purana (Chapters 42 through 55, and 106 - Nagaradi Vastu)
> - Matsya Purana (Chapters 252 through 270)
> - Maya samgraha
> - Prasada kirtana
> - Prasada Lakshana
> - Tachchu sastra (primarily home design for families)
> - Manushyalaya Lakshana (primarily human dwelings)
> - [[Manushyalaya Chandrika]]
> - Mantra dipika
> - Mana kathana (measurement principles)
> - Manava vastu lakshana
> - Manasollasa (chapters on house layout, mostly ancient cooking recipes)
> - Raja griha nirmana (architecture and construction principles for royal palaces)
> - Rupa mandana
> - Vastu chakra
> - Vastu tattva
> - Vastu nirnaya
> - Vastu purusha lakshana
> - Vastu prakasa
> - Vastu pradipa
> - Vastu manjari
> - Vastu mandana
> - Vastu lakshana
> - Vastu vichara
> - Vastu vidya
> - Vastu vidhi
> - Vastu samgraha
> - Vastu sarvasva
> - Vimana lakshana (tower design)
> - Visvakarma prakasa (home, roads, water tanks and public works architecture)
> - Vaikhanasa
> - Sastra jaladhi ratna
> - Sipla prakasa
> - Silpakala Dipika
> - Silpartha sastra
> - Sanatkumara vastu sastra

You can find list in Devanagari also - [प्रमुख वास्तुशास्त्रीय ग्रन्थ](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0#.E0.A4.AA.E0.A5.8D.E0.A4.B0.E0.A4.AE.E0.A5.81.E0.A4.96_.E0.A4.B5.E0.A4.BE.E0.A4.B8.E0.A5.8D.E0.A4.A4.E0.A5.81.E0.A4.B6.E0.A4.BE.E0.A4.B8.E0.A5.8D.E0.A4.A4.E0.A5.8D.E0.A4.B0.E0.A5.80.E0.A4.AF_.E0.A4.97.E0.A5.8D.E0.A4.B0.E0.A4.A8.E0.A5.8D.E0.A4.A5)

You can find some of available work on Vastu Shashtra at [Sthapatya Veda](http://www.peterffreund.com/Vedic_Literature/Vedic%20Literature%20Unicode/Upaveda/Sthapatya%20Veda/) which are:

- Kamikagama
- kashyapa shilpa
- kiranagama
- manasara
- manushyalaya chandrika
- samaranganasutradhara
- vastusutra upanishad
- vishvakarma vastu shastra
- yogajagama

Following are popular or best sources for Vastu Shashtra:

1. Mansaar Shilp Shashtra
2. Brihat Smhita
3. Vishwakarma Vastu Shashtra
4. Vishwakarma Shilp
5. Vastu Sutra
6. Vishwakarma Prakash

Vastu Mandala Purush from Hindupedia:

> [image: Vastu Mandala Purush]
>   <sub>(source: [hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/eng/images/c/c5/Vastu-purusha-mandala-image.gif))</sub>

Comment: Outstanding list, and thank you for the link to download Manushalaya Candrika. I've been looking for this for some time. I think this still begs the question as to whether any of the original vedanga from Atharva-veda on silpa-shastra remains, or whether it is all through these later literatures and Puranas (similar situation to Ayurveda).