# What type of Shashtra is Vastu?

Tags: scripture, vastu-shastra

In the [accepted answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16226/16030) to [What are 16 shastras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7890/16030), the division of 18 Vidyas into 4 categories is explained:

1. The Vedas
2. The Vedanga
3. Upanga
4. Upveda

The given examples of these categories add up to 18 without including Vastu, and none of them seem to contain Vastu within them. Still, it stands to reason that Vastu must lie within one of these categories since its considered a shashtra.

---

The question, [Are there any surviving vedangas on vastu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44869/16030), appears to imply that Vastu is a Vedanga.

---

However, [the answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16713/16030) to the question [What are the best resources for Vastu Shastra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15051/16030) states that:

> Sthapatya Veda is an upaveda of Atharvaveda.

> Vishwakarma is believed to be an expounder of Vashtu Shashtra also known as (or includes) Shilp Shashtra.

This seems to indicate that Vastu is actually an Upveda.

---

Thus my question is, **what kind of Vidya/ Shashtra does Vastu come under?**